# Oracle Forms Vs APEX

Tags: oracleforms, oracle-apex

Why are companies and developers migrating from Oracle Forms to APEX?

I need the answer of this question as I am going to develop new application, and I'm hesitating between Oracle Forms and APEX

Answer (score 5):

Because Oracle decided to kill Oracle Forms; 
This is about 'job security' - Oracle company made a huge mistake creating perfect tool for front-end development. Oracle Forms is very easy to learn, has huge functionality, you can do pretty much everything with Forms, and in a very short time. An application that takes months of development in APEX can be implemented less then in a week with Oracle Forms and it will be faster and with better usability. This means , the company has nothing else to develop in this field. Profit-wise this is a disaster. No software company wants to release a perfect product, exactly as no doctor wants all people to become healthy. So they claimed it as an 'old', 'mastodon' etc etc, stopped supporting and offered that JDeveloper 'instead' which turned out to be so messy and complicated that nobody even wants to migrate there; so developers had to start using htmlDB which was very primitive. Now with APEX we have GUI features, like, 20 years old style, a real zoo under the hood, and all forums are flooded with questions like 'how do I adjust column width?'
So this 'progress' took us way back into the past, but what's more important, it gave the company another 20 years of development (and SALES!) until they will manage to get to where they were with Forms. Profit!

Answer (score 4):

Oracle Forms is an old technology. Originally in character mode for dumb terminals in a typical client-server architecture. Due it's large installed base by e.g. institutionals, Forms survided every technology innovations, upgraded from thick clients to thin clients. Actually its a mastodon, not easy to learn, outdated.
It's more likely existing Forms are moved to Apex pages.

Answer (score -1):

Oracle states in this document from april 2014, that Oracle Forms will be supported, quoting "indefinitely" from page 8. http://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lifetime-support-middleware-069163.pdf .
No need to worry ...