# Oracle APEX 5 vs Oracle Forms and reports 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracleforms

I'm making this report about the migration of oracle forms and reports 6i to another technology (Oracle forms & report 12c Or Oracle APEX), and i'm making this comparative table of apex and oracles forms 12c of these points:

- Prerequisites
- Cost
- Productivity
- ease of use
- Speed
- Maintenance
- Deployment
- Security
- Scalability
- Support
- Community

and i would like the opinion of someone who has worked with both or at least with one of them and give me hand with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522865/oracle-forms-vs-apex#5526435). & [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:9525845800346610457)  by Tom Kyte and [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/apex-for-forms-098747.html) on OTN and [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Oracle-Apex-Oracle-APP-and-Oracle-Forms-Reports).
Also, APEX has a [migration tool](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEMIG/converting-Oracle-forms-application.htm#AEMIG163) when you're ready to make the jump.